# Biztalk message properties visible across applications?

Tags: biztalk

I have an existing schemas assembly from an already deployed BizTalk application. This assembly contains a property schema containing some properties which are promoted from the message body.

The problem I am having is that I want to configure a send port in a different BizTalk application with a subscription based on the value of the promoted property from that assembly.

However, I can't use this property for filtering because it doesn't show up in the list of properties in the send port filters dialogue.

There seems to be some "blocking" going on - because I am trying to filter based on a schema which is defined in a different application.

Is there any way around this? Has anyone got any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I worked out that you can do this by manually editing the bindings file and adding in your filter expression there.